# My app does not appear in the share menu from the Photos app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, plist, capacitor

I have a Ionic (capacitor) ios app and I want to be able to open files in it via the 'share' menu in other apps. I don't want to use a share extension since I don't need additional windows, and it's overhead. I added the ability to open PDF files and images to my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>PDF Document</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Image File</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.image</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

In javascript, I have the following code:

```js
...
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

...
App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data) => {
      console.log(data.url);
});
```

And everything works great! I get PDF images when I click on "share" in the "Files" or "Safari" app. I see my app in the list, but if I do it from the "Photos" app, my app is not in the list. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have a similar problem on iOS. I get a path for the file, but I don't have permission to open the file. How did you solve the access authorization?

Comment: Yes, sure. The only way to do this is with a share extension. There are simply no other options for "photo".